# Regex to allow only numbers not alphanumeric , letters and negative asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

hey everyone i want to know that i want to match regex only positive integers and dont allow alphanumeric letters and negative integer. 
i am using this ajax but it's not work as expected what should i do please help me

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format")]
public int? estddays { get; set; }
```

Comment: Give a sample input, a sample output of that regex, and a sample of what you expect.

Comment: when i input any letter it does not any error. if i input negative value it shows invalid format

Comment: Try the opposite: `@"^[^0-9]+$"`. Does anything change? If not, the reason is not with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use start anchor with a an optional `+` symbol at start:

```
@"^\+?[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: i am using this regex when i input letter but it does not show any errors

Comment: I can only test this regex independently but it doesn't allow any letters.

Comment: how can i handle null values in this regex

Comment: To allow empty values use: `@"^(\+?[0-9]+)?$"` regex

Comment: In that case given regex will work as it doesn't allow empty values

Answer (score 0):

To match only positive numbers you could use:

```
^(?<!-)\d+$
```

The escaped string is:

```
@"^(?<!-)\d+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you are looking to allow a number like 132 but error on 133.  Also error on -132.  To do that, try this regex:

`[RegularExpression(@"^(?<!-)\d*[02468]$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format")]`